# ERROR: Unhandled exception: Out of local stack - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I was trying to write a simple version of `length/3` in Prolog.

If you look at the standard implementation of `length/2` it is something as below:

```
length([], 0).
length([Head|Tail], N) :-
    length(Tail, N1),
    N is 1+N1.
```

While my code uses almost the same idea but I get the error "out of local stack", and I think it happens because of deep recursion. I couldn't figure why. And my code:

```
mylength(_, [], 0).
mylength([H1|T1], [H1copy|T1copy], N) :-
    mylength([H1|T1], [T1copy], N1),
    N is N1 + 1.
```

Comment: You put `T1copy` in a list. Modify `[T1copy]` to `T1copy`.

Comment: What should `mylength/3` desribe exactly? It seems that you want another list of the same length.

Comment: its a kinda of compicated :)

Comment: In any case: note  your first definition of `length/2` is not the "standard implementation"! For your definition loops for `length(L,2)`! but it should give exactly one answer `L = [_,_]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate `mylength/3` has the following problem. I assume that
you want to run it with the mode `mylength(+,-,-)`. It is then the
case that the first argument is not decending.

The problem is the second clause, where the first argument `[H1|T1]`
in the head is passed unchanged to the first argument of the same
predicate in the body, contrary to what happens in length/2. Resulting 
in infinite recursion, since the given second argument `[T1copy]` does not 
match the first clause.

The infinite recursion can lead to a memory exhaust, since for
example each invocation will generate a new variable for H1copy.
The particular error message depends on the Prolog system.

Bye

P.S.: That there might be something wrong is aleady seen
when consulting the predicate. One gets a singleton warning
for `H1copy`.

But for example in the newest SWI-Prolog version, the
out of local stack error will take some time, since
SWI-Prolog does carbage collection. After ^C and g
I see:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.16)
Copyright (c) 1990-2014 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam

Action (h for help) ? goals

[552,959] mylength([1, 2, 3], [[]], _G40)
[552,958] mylength('<garbage_collected>', '<garbage_collected>', _G40)
[552,957] mylength('<garbage_collected>', '<garbage_collected>', _G40)
[552,956] mylength('<garbage_collected>', '<garbage_collected>', _G40)
[552,955] mylength('<garbage_collected>', '<garbage_collected>', _G40)
```

I guess the above means that at the current moment
where I have interrupted the Prolog interpreter the 
call stack had already a depth of 552959, i.e. half
a million!

After running for several minutes, I get the following
error message in SWI-Prolog: `ERROR: Out of local stack`.

Comment: P.S.: The example is quite a challenge for a prolog system that produces a stack trace, since the stack trace would be huge.